# Xcode warning: "Unused variable" when NSLog use it

Tags: ios, xcode, warnings

I dont understand why when i select "Profile" i get several "Unused variable" warnings.

Like this code snippet:

```
+ (void) printReadingsForDevice:(NSMutableArray*)device
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter1 setDateFormat:@"HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy."];
    [dateFormatter1 setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
    
    for (NSDictionary *reading in device)
    {
        NSNumber *value = [reading objectForKey:keyValue];
        NSNumber *batteryState = [reading objectForKey:keyBatteryState];
        NSNumber *wifiConnectionTime = [reading objectForKey:keyWiFiConnectionTime];
        NSNumber *timestamp = [reading objectForKey:keyTimestamp];
        
        NSLog(@"value: %6.2f, batteryState: %3d, wifiConnectionTime: %5.1f, timestamp: %@, date: %@", [value floatValue], [batteryState integerValue], [wifiConnectionTime floatValue], timestamp, [dateFormatter1 stringFromDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[timestamp doubleValue] / 1000.0f]]);
    }
}
```

This is simple utility method to print some values.

[image: Screenshot]

Why is the profiler complaining?

Comment: Actually you are not using the values other than `NSLog`, however you can opt to override..

Comment: Because it is assumed that you wont release the app with `NSLog`, then all these will be unused.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya What does "release the app" mean? Like switching to `Not running state` and purged from memory.